# Bootpag add li class and a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bootpag (http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.XBEmJRMzYcg).

I want to add `page-item` class to every `li` and `page-link` class to each `a` element.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried and explain how it failed

Comment: just i dont know. how can add every li class page-item. every a class page-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, adding classes is a pretty basic operation with jQuery:

```
jQuery('a').addClass('page-link');
jQuery('li').addClass('page-item');
```

I don't know why you sited a whole piece of code which seems unrelated to the main question.

Comment: i mean not every li class; bootpag add class.

Comment: pagenation every li and a class

Comment: @Sinem sorry, it's unclear what you are saying. *bootpag add class* – what does that mean? Do you need to add those classes to `a` elements with `bootpag` class and to `li` elements with `bootpag` class?

Comment: @Sinem or do you mean you need to add classes to `a` and `li` elements inside bootpag pagination panel?